# How to tell if sqlite database file is valid or not

Tags: database, file, sqlite, detection

In the code below, `pathToNonDatabase` is the path to a simple text file, not a real sqlite database.  I was hoping for `sqlite3_open` to detect that, but it doesn't (`db` is not `NULL`, and `result` is `SQLITE_OK`).  So, how to detect that a file is not a valid sqlite database?

```
sqlite3 *db = NULL;
int result = sqlite3_open(pathToNonDatabase, &db);

if((NULL==db) || (result!=SQLITE_OK)) { 
   // invalid database
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

sqlite opens databases lazily. Just do something immediately after opening that requires it to be a database.

The best is probably `pragma schema_version;`.

- This will report 0 if the database hasn't been created (for instance, an empty file). In this case, it's safe work with (and run `CREATE TABLE`, etc)
- If the database has been created, it will return how many revisions the schema has gone through. This value might not be interesting, but that it's not zero is.
- If the file exists and isn't a database (or empty), you'll get an error.

If you want a somewhat more thorough check, you can use `pragma quick_check;`. This is a lighter-weight integrity check, which skips checking that the contents of the tables line up with the indexes. It can still be very slow.

Avoid `integrity_check`. It not only checks every page, but then verifies the contents of the tables against the indexes. This is positively glacial on a large database.

Comment: "pragma schema_version;" throws "database is locked" error sometimes. I'll give the "pragma quick_check;" a try

Comment: If your database is locked, it's locked. Everything will fail. Try again when it isn't locked. :)

Comment: You're right. Everything fails when the database is locked. Even selects. In my case I wanted to determine if the file was a Sqlite3 database. If I get the "database is locked" error I think it is safe to assume the file is a Sqlite3 database.

Comment: This doesn't work for an encrypted database (e.g. using SQLCipher).

Comment: No, it won't, unless you unlock it with the same key. That's how SQLite was designed, and SQLCipher is a hack on that.

Comment: Using `pragma schema_version;` is a solution of the question. For an existing text file I get `sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is not a database` (python sqlite3). However, for a non existing file, `sqlite.connect()` creates a database for you, which may not be what you want. The check also comes back "OK" when the file is empty. For these cases, I ended up using OS file checks.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone needing to do this in C# with System.Data.SQLite you can start a transaction, and then immediately roll it back as follows:-

```
    private bool DatabaseIsValid(string filename)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=" + filename + ";FailIfMissing=True;"))
        {
            try
            {
                db.Open();
                using (var transaction = db.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Debug(ex.Message, ex);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

If the file is not a valid database the following `SQLiteException` is thrown - file is encrypted or is not a database (`System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteErrorCode.NotADb`). If you aren't using encrypted databases then this solution should be sufficient.
(Only the 'db.Open()' was required for version 1.0.81.0 of System.Data.SQLite but when I upgraded to version 1.0.91.0 I had to insert the inner using block to get it to work).

Answer (score 4):

I think a `pragma integrity_check;` could do it.

Comment: Be warned; this can be very slow if your database is large.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only to check if the file is a valid sqlite database then you can check with this function:

```
    private bool CheckIfValidSQLiteDatabase(string databaseFilePath)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(databaseFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, 16);
        }
        string gg = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        return gg.Contains("SQLite format");
    }
```

as stated in the documentation:
[sqlite database header](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#the_database_header)

Comment: This will detect if the file is something else than a sqlite database file, but it will not detect a broken sqlite database file.